# How to write stream in the same browser window using OutputStreamWriter?

Tags: java, html, http, servlets

In the server side code, I am writing a string (which gets written on a browser page) using OutputStreamWriter. This gets written in a new window. I need to be able to write this in the same window.

The class extends HttpServlet and following is the structure of the code:

```
void foo(HttpServletResponse response...) {
...
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.write("Hello World!"); // Or some html string
    out.flush();  
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server side (the servlet) don't and can't open a new window (*fortunately*, otherwise spamming the client with popups would be tremendously easy...). The client (the browser) is the only who can open a new window. Most likely you've used one of the following constructs in HTML or JavaScript which will show the result in a new window:

```html
<form action="servleturl" target="_blank">
```

or

```html
<a href="servleturl" target="_blank">
```

or

```html
<script>window.open('servleturl', 'windowname');</script>
```

You need to **remove** the `target="_blank"` to get the response in the current window, or in case you're using JavaScript, to use `window.location = 'servleturl';` instead.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, emitting HTML in a servlet is a poor practice. Use JSP instead.

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)

Comment: I am pretty sure I don't have any code in the client side that opens a new window - I have checked. Also to make sure, I even printed out a string "Hello World" with no tags; and it got printed on a new window.

Comment: Enter the servlet URL straight in browser address bar. You'll see that it doesn't open a new window (if it does, then your browser is broken).

Comment: Figured it out. The URL does open in the same window. The problem was with the link that redirects to that URL. You are right about the server not having the capability of opening a new browser window from an existing one.